# Enabling Hyper-V on Windows 10 not working

Tags: windows, hyper-v, dism

When I run `Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName:Microsoft-Hyper-V-All` I get Error Code: 0x800f0831

I know online it says it is typically a .NET error, but I have double checked that .NET is installed properly.

I've tried the scan now commands and I've tried enabling it in safe mode and through Powershell with no luck.

Why can't I enable Hyper-V on this laptop?

Comment: What version of Windows do you use? Do you have the last updates? I used that command without the parameter -Online and works for me. Did you try it?

Comment: I currently cannot install Hyper-V also. Might be Windows problem (I am using Windows 10 Pro ver. 1709.